# Code-oriented editor : Must-have features?

Tags: text, ide, editor, text-editor

I hope this question doesn't fall into the "subjective question" case, but here's what :

I've been coding for almost 18 years, and having migrated to Macs for the last year or so, it was inevitable to start thinking about writing a code editor from scratch - probably, just to try this thing out, or to make something that perfectly suits my needs. And I was wondering :

- What are the absolute MUST-HAVEs of a good code editor*? (by order of priority, if possible)
- If we're talking about a not-so-conventional feature, could you give me an example of actual implementation of that particular feature? ("xxxxx" like in Notepad++ on Windows).

Looking forward to see your answers...

**Well, there is sometimes a thin line between what could be considered as an "Editor" and an "IDE", but let's just not exclude more... IDE-oriented ones...*

Comment: Must have: it must be able to do everything emacs can do. Go.

Comment: Well, I've been working on this new thing for a fair amount of time (around 10 months) and I'm actually in the process of eliminating some of the not-so-valuable features. I need something simple-yet-powerful, not with tons of all-too-geeky hidden features. :-)

Comment: So pick one of the existing tools and enjoy. Personally, I think the idea of an editor (or anything, really) built around a "live" language is neat. SmallTalk extends this notion well beyond Emacs, though ;-)

Comment: Curiosity is the mother of invention! :-)

Comment: You might as well see [what-are-some-of-the-things-you-hate-about-your-favorite-editor-ide?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428486/what-are-some-of-the-things-you-hate-about-your-favorite-editor-ide?rq=1) And also [do-you-draw-a-distinction-between-text-editors-and-ides?rq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/199207/do-you-draw-a-distinction-between-text-editors-and-ides?rq=1). Can be of some help

Answer (score 0):

- Syntax highlighting with error checking.
- "Go to Definition"/"Go to Declaration". Other types of quick "Go To"s.
- As many kinds of autocompletion as you can possibly imagine.
- Vim mode or being a Vim clone (command/edit mode dichotomy).

There's a lot of other nice-to-have features like automatic refactoring but the above I believe are definitive traits of a source code editor.